# Are all "forms" linear maps from vector spaces to fields?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, quadratic-forms

It seems that whenever we call something a "form": quadratic form, linear form, bilinear form, one-form, two-form, etc. it is always a linear (or perhaps not?) map from some vector space (or elsewhere?) to a field of scalars. Is this in general always true?

This is simply a question of vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

It is often, but not always the case.
For example, a modular form is not of this type (it is a map from the complex upper half-plane to itself satisfying certain conditions).

Comment: And indeed, a 2-form is not a map from a vector space to a field, unless the underlying manifold is a single point. The question does make me wonder, however, how the word "form" got to have this kind of meaning.